# Using WebGrid to show a list of email addresses (strings) - ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I am declaring a WebGrid as follows:

```
@{
    WebGrid grid = null;
    if (Model.EmailAddressesOfChosenClient.Count<string>() != 0)
    {
        grid = new WebGrid(Model.EmailAddressesOfChosenClient, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
    }
}
```

Then I am trying to Render the WebGrid as follows without specifying any columns:

```
<div id="gridContent">
@{ if (grid != null)
   {
      @grid.GetHtml()
   }
}
</div>
```

My EmailAddressesOfChosenClient property of the Model is IEnumerable of strings where each string is an email address. I would like the WebGrid to contain a single column with title "Email Address" followed by rows of email address strings.

If I render it this way however, my WebGrid shows up with column heading "Length" and the rows contain the length of each email address string.

Why is that? How do I configure things so that I show the email addresses in the rows and with the right column heading? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is that?

Because if you do not explicitly specify the columns, the helper uses reflection to inspect the public properties of the type and autogenerates a column for them. So the `System.String` has the `.Length` public property and thus you get a column for it.

You will need to use a custom column:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("email", format: item => item)
    )
)
```

Alternatively you could define a view model and have your `IEnumerable<T>` use this view model instead of string.

Comment: *** YOU ARE A STAR ***